# Trying to install Foxit Reader 2.4.1 on 16.04 - message cannot execute binary file

Tags: software-installation, foxitreader

Using the instructions on "https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/" I downloaded the software and followed the instructions.  On the last step I got message: " `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`"  I selected the 64 bit download. I have also tried other instructions for older Foxit Reader versions, all gave same problem.

```
Please follow the steps below to install Foxit Reader for Linux:
  •   Change to the directory containing the downloaded
      file (used /tmp as the example):
      # cd /tmp 
  •   Uncompress the executable
      # gzip -d 'FoxitReader_version_Setup.run.tar.gz'
  •   Untar the .tar file:
      # tar xvf 'FoxitReader_version_Setup.run.tar'
  •   Run the installer:
      # ./'FoxitReader_version_Setup.run'  ***Error on this step***
  •   Follow the steps on the screen to complete the
      installation
```

**Added Here is print out of terminal session.**

```
bob@bob-PORTEGE-Z30-B:~$ cd Downloads
bob@bob-PORTEGE-Z30-B:~/Downloads$ ls
FoxitReader2.4.1.0609_Server_x64_enu_Setup.run.tar.gz
linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
mfcj885dwcupswrapper-1.0.0-0.i386.deb
mfcj885dwlpr-1.0.0-0.i386.deb
bob@bob-PORTEGE-Z30-B:~/Downloads$ gzip -d 'FoxitReader2.4.1.0609_Server_x64_enu_Setup.run.tar.gz'
bob@bob-PORTEGE-Z30-B:~/Downloads$ ls
FoxitReader2.4.1.0609_Server_x64_enu_Setup.run.tar
linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
mfcj885dwcupswrapper-1.0.0-0.i386.deb
mfcj885dwlpr-1.0.0-0.i386.deb
bob@bob-PORTEGE-Z30-B:~/Downloads$ tar xvf 'FoxitReader2.4.1.0609_Server_x64_enu_Setup.run.tar'
FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.1.0609(r08f07f8).x64.run
bob@bob-PORTEGE-Z30-B:~/Downloads$ ls
FoxitReader2.4.1.0609_Server_x64_enu_Setup.run.tar
FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.1.0609(r08f07f8).x64.run
linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
mfcj885dwcupswrapper-1.0.0-0.i386.deb
mfcj885dwlpr-1.0.0-0.i386.deb
bob@bob-PORTEGE-Z30-B:~/Downloads$ ./'FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.1.0609(r08f07f8).x64.run'
bash: ./FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.1.0609(r08f07f8).x64.run: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
bob@bob-PORTEGE-Z30-B:~/Downloads$
```

**Problem resolved**
 - was trying to install 64bit software on 32 bit ubuntu.  Note: the hardware, BIOS, says it is 64 but ubuntu says 32.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `file ./'FoxitReader_version_Setup.run'` and `uname -a`

Comment: It usually helps to include the whole terminal session with your question. Too often there are other messages, warnings or errors that went unnoticed and would help answering the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you typed the instructions exactly as shown in your question, you will fail.  `Foxit Reader` expects that you will replace "*version*" with the version number of the file that you have downloaded.  Try the following:

In a terminal, change to the directory that has the downloaded file you want to install.  Please make sure that there is only one version of the Foxit software in the directory...

Enter `gzip -d Foxit` then press <kbd>tab</kbd>, and <kbd>enter</kbd> - no space between the <kbd>t</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd>.  This should complete the command with the name of the gz file.

Enter `tar xvf Foxit` then press <kbd>tab</kbd>, and <kbd>enter</kbd> - this should complete the command with the name of the tar file.

Enter `./Foxit` then press <kbd>tab</kbd>, and <kbd>enter</kbd> - this should complete the command with the name of the executable file.